# Output to the 1st input of a function in Julia

Tags: julia

On [this page](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/tutorials/ode_example.html#Example-2:-Solving-Systems-of-Equations-1) about differential equations, it writes about writing the output to the 1st input of the function we want to solve. For example suppose we have these set of differential equations:

[image]

the code in Julia defining the function is:

```
function lorenz(du,u,p,t)
du[1] = 10.0*(u[2]-u[1])
du[2] = u[1]*(28.0-u[3]) - u[2]
du[3] = u[1]*u[2] - (8/3)*u[3]
end
```

Here the output is `du` which is also the input. It seems this way of defining a function has something to do with the array allocation.
I do not understand what they mean by giving the output to the 1st input of the function.

Comment: It means that you modify (or 'mutate') the array that is referred to by the first input variable, instead of creating a new array and returning that. It's a technique that is often used to avoid creating/allocating new objects, because allocation uses memory and slows down your code.

Comment: Thanks. Does Python have this feature too?

Comment: Yes, in Python too, you can mutate input variables inside a function, and the have the changes be visible outside the function.